# How to prevent a blank space when scrolling with a sidebar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, sidebar

I'm currently building a sidebar using bootstrap.
I have the bar built, however when I scroll down the page, a blank space appears between the sidebar and the navbar. Is there anyway that I can make the navbar stay stationary, or fill in the blank space when the page is scrolled down? I have included screenshots and code. [Normal, before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lEPv.png)

[After Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WITFy.png)

Code listed below:

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "navbar-header">
            <button type = "button" class="navbar-toggle" data-
toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class = "navbar-brand" href="Home.html">Stephens Catering</a>
        </div>

        <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
    <a class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
    href="OurProducts.html">Our Products
                    <span class = "caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="Cookers.html">Cookers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Fridges.html">Fridges</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Misc.html">Misc</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
</span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in">
</span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!--The sidebar for the products pages -->
<div id = "wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id = "sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class = "sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">Categories</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Cookers.html">Cookers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Fridges.html">Fridges</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Misc.html">Misc</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Sidebar Wrapper -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<!-- Button to toggle sidebar menu -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-lg-12">
                <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The stylesheet:

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
```

}

```
/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
padding-left: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
padding-left:250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
z-index: 1000;
position:fixed;
left:250px;
width:0;
height:100%;
margin-left: -250px;
overflow-y: auto;
background: #000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
width:250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
width:100%;
position:absolute;
padding:15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
position:absolute;
margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:250%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
text-indent:20px;
line-height: 40px
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color:#999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color:#fff;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li focus {
text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
height:65px;
font-size:18px;
line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
color:#999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > sidebar-brand a:hover{
color:#fff;
backround:none;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
#wrapper {
    padding-left:0;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left:250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    width:0;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width:250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    padding:20px;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right:0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Having some trouble recreating your problem in CodePen, could you add more code or point out what I am missing? https://codepen.io/CapySloth/pen/ayNdPK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is using the `position:fixed` in the `#sidebar-wrapper` css class which causes it to stick to the positioned place on the screen without scroll affect. If you want it to stick right below the top navbar then change it to `position:absolute` and your problem will be hopefully resolved. And if you want it to stick to top and also keep the black background of the sidebar to follow through to the bottom then change `#sidebar-wrapper` `position:relative`.

The best way for you to understand this is to understand the effects of the values of the position property. Following is a link to the w3schools definition of position property and it's values with description.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped alot, the only issue im having now is the positioning of my toggle menu button, but with a bit of messing that can be fixed..many thanks!

Comment: No problem glad to help. If my answer helped you out then please mark it and vote it. Thanks

Comment: done! still a new user to my rep isnt high enough to upvote yet, when it is ill come back

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your actual sidebar-wrapper css rule:

```
.sidebar-wrapper{
top:0;
}
```